# Django:How to load new recent comments in Django template without refreshing a page?

Tags: python, django, ajax

Actually, i am working with the comments section in Django.

comments model in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class comment(models.Model):
    message=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="my_comment",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post=models.ForeignKey(posti,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="post_comment") #posti is a post model

    class Meta:
        ordering=['time']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message
```

simple view in views.py to create a new comment.

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_comment(request,pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj=posti.objects.get(pk=pk)
        value=request.POST.get("message")
        new=comment(message=value,user=request.user,post=obj)
        new.save()
        return HttpResponse(new)
```

HTML file to load posts as well as comments.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>{{post_data}}</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="add">
        {% for i in comments%}
            <div><p>{{i.message}}</p><br><span>{{i.time}}{{i.user}}</span></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div>
        <form id="my_form" action="{% url 'a' pk=id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input name="message" type="text"><br>
            <button id="click" type="submit">Comment</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <h1></h1>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#my_form").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:$(this).attr("action"),
                type:$(this).attr("method"),
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    //$("h1").text(data['time']);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I'm using ajax so that users can post new comments on a post without refreshing a page. New comments in the database are storing without refreshing a page but how I can load new comments in this HTML file without a refreshing page. If you have any idea please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax at frontend side
When you add comment 
It calles api (django also supports ajax calls)
Api call method (defined on view) add the comment into db 
Send response to ajax call ( as per your application logic)
In this case you need to all comments for a post to ajax call
Write down logic to add row in your comment teble at frontend once api response is recieved.

This will be done asynchronously with out refreshing your page.

In your code snippet
In the starting of your code add script tag for javascript support
Give id to your div inside for loop
And once success response is received: 
Use

`document.getElementById('id').innerhtml += "<p>" + data.comment.message + " " + data.comment.user + "</p>"`

To understand this, refer to getElement function in JavaScript.
I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the response from your ajax call is as below:

```
data = {"message": "----", "time":"----", "user":"---"}
```

Then this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    url:$(this).attr("action"),
    type:$(this).attr("method"),
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    success:function(data){
        //$("h1").text(data['time']);
        console.log(data);

        $('#add').append(
            "<div><p>" + data.message + "</p><br><span>" + data.time + " " + date.user + "</span></div>"
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@OBAA and @nilayshah thanks for the answer. but both of your logic is different and not suitable for this question so what i have done.

Hello everyone, after searching on the internet i got a solution to this problem.

i just create a new template name div.html in my template folders. Then i retrieve new recent comments on this template.when my ajax gets a success message then i load this template div.html in my main template.

div.html

```
<div><p>{{i.message}}</p><br><span>{{i.time}}{{i.user}}</span></div>
```

my update view for creating a new comment.

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_comment(request,pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj=posti.objects.get(pk=pk)
        value=request.POST.get("message")
        new=comment(message=value,user=request.user,post=obj)
        new.save()
        x=new.user
        x=list(x.my_comment.all())[-1]
        return render(request,'div.html',{'i':x})
```

when ajax get a success message then i just append data in my comments div and reset the form, like this.

```
                success:function(data){
                    $("#add").append(data);
                    $("#my_form")[0].reset();
                }
```